# Notify browser UI about SignalR requests to the server

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I ma using SignalR in the browser. Some request (calling function on the server) are long and I would like to show spinner/loading-bar.

Can I somehow hook for an event when this function is started and when it returns back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out what you mean - I think basically you want some way to hook into the start of a call and the end of a call (to load and unload a spinner)?

I've done this in two different ways - firstly as a one-off (first example), and then more systematically (the second example). Hopefully one of these will be what you need.

```
$.connection.myHub.server.hubMethod().done(function () {
                                //called on success
                            }).fail(function (e) {
                                //called on failure - I don't recommend reading e
                            }).always(function() {
                                //called regardless
                                spinner.close();
});
spinner.open(); // must be triggerd AFTER call incase exception thrown (due to connection not being up yet)
```

If you don't like that - perhaps because you call hub methods in hundreds of different sections of codes, then there are other tricks which are a bit more complicated. Lets see:

```
function SetupSpinnerOnCallToSignalrMethod(hubServer, method, spinnerStartCallback, spinnerEndCallback) {
    var prevFunc = hubServer[method];
    hubServer[method] = function () {
        var ret = prevFunc.apply(this, arguments);
        spinnerStartCallback(); // must be triggerd AFTER call incase exception thrown (due to connection not being up yet)
        ret.always(function() {
            spinnerEndCallback();
        });
        return ret;
    };
}

//then call this for each method
SetupSpinnerOnCallToSignalrMethod($.connection.myHub.server,
                                  "hubMethod",
                                  function() { spinner.open(); },
                                  function() { spinner.close(); }
);

//the server call should then work exactly as before, but the spinner open and close calls are invoked each time.
```